# Thymeleaf: enable/disable a button if input is empty

Tags: java, thymeleaf

I wanted to understand if I can use `th:disabled` much like I can use the old AngularJS 1.x `ng-disabled`?

I cannot have any javascript in my html and I am looking for a solution to check if the field is empty before enabling the `submit` button.

Comment: Without JS it's hardly possible... the only thing that can be used - native HTML validators: `<input required  ...>` - that will block submission

Comment: @FieryCat I was afraid somebody would say that.

Comment: @DenissM. - if you use required, the user won't be able to submit the form until it fills in everything, and the browser will prompt the user what fields must be filled in. What's the problem? demo: https://www.wufoo.com/html5/attributes/09-required.html

Comment: @aepure the problem is that some of my users browsers do not support html5...

Comment: @DenissM. - well you can still use 'required' for most usage and also on the server validate and return the same form + a validation message. I don't think there's much more you can do without javascript. It wouldn't be that bad

Comment: @aepure it isn't very bad. Just a lot of not entirely necessary code...

Comment: @DenissM. - if your customers need it, you need it :)